# Should I create a separate package for code shared between multiple libraries to be published on PyPI?

Tags: python, dependencies, packaging, pypi, code-duplication

I'm currently creating two open source libraries (different uses, so no sense merging them). Let's call them A and B. I have a set of utility functions and modules that both libraries use. Normally I'd create a third package called "utils" and work from there. But publishing an utils package on PyPI must not be the best idea (name overlap, hard to define what the package contains, as it has a bit of everything, etc.).

The question is, what would be the best way of allowing both libraries use those functions without replicating the `utils` code in both (as it is non-trivial and I don't want to have duplicity). There is an option, since library `A` depends on (adds as a requirement) library `B`, so I could create a `B.utils` subpackage and roll with it, but I prefer another design, just in case a third use case comes up and I don't want to require a different package just for those unrelated `.utils` functions.

I know the question is a bit open-ended, but I'd like to get some tips so I don't regret my decision.

Edit:
As requested by comment, I describe what my `torch-utils` package contains. Both libraries are about PyTorch stuff, so `utils` has:

- `Module`: an inheritance of `torch.nn.Module` that saves a `device` attribute and updates it when the module changes device.
- `training` module: a module containing generic training recipes for training networks.
- `prob` module: probability functions. Specifically, contains implementations for running the log-sum-exp trick for Monte Carlo expectations of log probabilities.

among other things.

As you see, it's not generic stuff that you can do with the standard library.

Comment: I think this depends on what your "utils" are, and how easy it would be to fulfil the 
same purposes with utilities from the standard library. It would be best to edit your question to be specific about what your utils do and why your libraries depend on them.

Comment: Edited with your suggestion. Basically, not standard library stuff

Comment: I think at least some of your "utils" modules are potentially publishable. The trick is just not calling them "utils". How about `pytorch-training-recipes`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm missing something, but can't you just name your `utils` package something more specific so that it does not conflict with any existing pip package?

If not, then maybe you can figure out a solution which just includes the utils package on build. You can do this on setup.py, so the only question that remains is to how to have the utils package present in 2 repositories (assuming that each library has its own repository). Perhaps you can use `git submodules` for this - I am not a particular fan, but they seem to solve this problem.